# Programatically adding an asp.net ajax DragPanelExtender

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I get the following error when I try to add an ajax DragPanelExtender programatically.

> The TargetControlID of '' is not
>   valid. A control with ID 'ajaxPanel'
>   could not be found.

Here's my code:-

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel ajaxPanel = new Panel();
        ajaxPanel.ID = "ajaxPanel";
        ajaxPanel.Height = 100;
        ajaxPanel.Width = 100;
        ajaxPanel.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;

        AjaxControlToolkit.DragPanelExtender panelExtender = new AjaxControlToolkit.DragPanelExtender();
        panelExtender.TargetControlID = ajaxPanel.UniqueID;
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(panelExtender);

    }
}
```

How do I fix this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there:

```
panelExtender.TargetControlID = ajaxPanel.UniqueID;
```

Instead of UniqueID use ID

**EDITED**:
You have created

```
Panel ajaxPanel = new Panel();
```

but didn't append to page:

```
Page.Form.Controls.Add(ajaxPanel);
```

Comment: @soontobeared my pardon! Not ClinetID but ID